# finding a specific td and assign the value to a text input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to iterate through a table and find specific text in td and assign it to a variable. This is what I have so far:

```
 var table = $(this).closest('table');

    $("td",table).each(function(){
        if($(this)+':contains("AD Login")') console.log($(this).next().text());
    });
```

However this code prints all the cells to the console, instead of the sibling of the found cell

Comment: I know that the problem is that the if statement always return true since AD Login does exist in a cell in my table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function with the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector (*jQuery version added: 1.1.4*).

```
$("td",table).each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":contains('AD Login')")) console.log($(this).next().text());
});
```

- Notice that [`.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) doesn't fit here for it can only *check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element.* (From the API).

---

Regarding what you've written in your comment - it always returns true because you're just concatenating `$(this)`'s *string value* to another string (":contains etc."). When converted to boolean type, string immediates are always true.

Comment: I did that but I got the error that contains is not a function. I believe the jquery I use is an older version. However, the use of "is" did the job

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: Not sure. probably 1.4 or something

Comment: What do you get from `$.fn.jquery`? This will tell you the version number, and this is important to know, if you want to ask for help (it lets us work out what methods are, and are not, available to you.

Comment: my jquery version is 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a contains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector.

Example :

```
var table = $(this).closest('table');

table.find('td:contains("AD Login")').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).next().text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an 'older' version of jQuery (from comments to another answer):

```
$("td",table).each(function(i,el){
    if ((el.textContent || el.innerText) == 'AD Login') {
        console.log($(this).next().text());
    }
});
```

The above will test that the text of the `td` is exactly equal to the string ('AD Login'), to check if that text is simply present within the text of the `td`:

```
$("td",table).each(function(i,el){
    if ((el.textContent || el.innerText).indexOf('AD Login') > -1) {
        console.log($(this).next().text());
    }
});
```

Comment: Using == is not the equivalent to `contains`... Maybe `indexOf()` etc.

Comment: This is true, but given the OP's proficiency with jQuery, I'm not convinced that ':contains()` or `.contains()` where the right approach anyway. Though I've updated the answer to approach from that direction.

Comment: The problem was with `.contains()`... It's not the same as `:contains`. Using `.is()` and `:contains` should work from version 1.1.4+

Comment: Yes, I know. I chose to post alternative approaches (since other answers already covered those).